# Bash: Maintaining a set of files and their gzipped equivalent

Tags: bash, synchronization, directory, compression, gzip

I have a directory tree in which there are some files and some subdirectories.

```
/
/file1.txt
/file2.png
/dir1
    /subfile1.gif
```

The objective is to have a script that generates a gzipped version of each file and saves it next to each file, with an added `.gz` suffix:

```
/
/file1.txt
/file1.txt.gz
/file2.png
/file2.png.gz
/dir1
    /subfile1.gif
    /subfile1.gif.gz
```

This would handle the creation of new `.gz` files.

Another part is deletion: Whenever a non-gzipped file is created, the script would need to delete the orphaned `.gz` version when it runs.

The last and trickiest part is modification: Whenever some (non-gzipped) files are changed, re-running the script would update the `.gz` version of only those changed files, based on file timestamp (`mtime`) comparison between a file and its gzipped version.

Is it possible to implement such a script in bash?

**Edit**: The goal of this is to have prepared compressed copies of each file for nginx to serve using the gzip_static module. It is not meant to be a background service which automatically compresses things as soon as anything changes, because nginx's gzip_static module is smart enough to serve content from the uncompressed version if no compressed version exists, or if the uncompressed version's timestamp is more recent than the gzipped version's timestamp. As such, this is a script that would run occasionally, whenever the server is not busy.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Believe it or not, this would be a *significant* amount of work and it appears that you want to simply outsource the task for free.  I'm happy to help you work through a problem, but you better pay me to write entire programs for you.

Comment: Let's say you want this for nginx to have -9 gz prepared.  Why don't you make a script for copying?  I don't see the benefit of having both versions in a directory

Comment: At least its a well defined problem ;-) +1 for good formatting and problem description, but I agree with Tim, show us what you've tried. There's one thing missing Etienne, your description almost sounds like you want all this to happen automatically, running in the back-ground as a service.  If this is your intent, please make it more definite. If you just want some utility scripts that accept arguments and run from the command line, please say that too. Good luck.

Comment: Did you look into inotify? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).  You could write a script that wakes for every file when the write to it completed.  If the file had .gz ext just ignore it, for all others create/recreate the .gz

Comment: @TimPote Well then it's just the "significant" that I needed to hear. I already got a partially-functional script for this using the `find` command's `-exec` argument, but it's not smart about orphans or already-existing `.gz` files. If there is no equivalently-simple way to do this in bash, then this answers my question with the answer "No" and I'd rather not try further and do it in Python ;)
@EricFortis I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. What would a "script for copying" do that would additionally make compressed copies?
@shellter No, not a background service, but unattended yes

Comment: Edited question to add the purpose this is trying to achieve, to clarify that it is not a background service

Comment: make would be a better choice than Python for this IMO.

Comment: I mean, have one directory for uncompressed files and a script to move after compressing to the web dir.

Comment: @EricFortis I guess that would make things less messy, yes, but it doesn't solve the main problem (what to compress, what orphans to delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  *.gz )
    # If it's an orphan, remove it
    test -f "${1%.gz}" || rm "$1" ;;
    # Otherwise, will be handled when the existing parent is handled
  * )
    make -f - <<'____HERE' "$1.gz"
%.gz: %
    # Make sure you have literal tab here!
    gzip -9 <$< >$@
____HERE
    ;;
esac
```

If you have a Makefile already, by all means use a literal file rather than a here document.

Integrating with `find` left as an exercise.  You might want to accept multiple target files and loop over them, if you want to save processes.

Comment: Thanks much, the `make` solution is quite elegant for this indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt at it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# you need to clean up .gz files when you remove things
find . -type f -perm -o=r -not -iname \*.gz | \
while read -r x
do
    if [ "$x" -nt "$x.gz" ]; then
        gzip -cn9 "$x" > "$x.gz"
        chown --reference="$x" "$x.gz"
        chmod --reference="$x" "$x.gz"
        touch --reference="$x" "$x.gz"
        if [ `stat -c %s "$x.gz"` -ge `stat -c %s "$x"` ]; then
            rm "$x.gz"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Stole most of it from here: https://superuser.com/questions/482787/gzip-all-files-without-deleting-them

Changes include:

- skipping .gz files
- adding -9 and -n to make the files smaller
- deleting files that ended up larger (unfortunately this means they will be retried every time you run the script.)
- made sure the owner, permissions, and timestamp on the compressed file matches the original
- only works on files that are readable by everyone

Comment: Could you create a small file to cache a list of those that get bigger? Maybe store CRC32s in that file also?